# using jQuery, how can I remove a dynamically added class to the head of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I use an inline editor to edit css classes, when a change is made I wish to remove the class definition and add it again, also user has option to delete the element using it so I need to delete the definition.

Adding works using this code:

```
$("<style>").prop("type", "text/css").html( "#my_element_"+MaxElements+" {"+ xCSSCode +"}").appendTo("head");
```

however I can't seem to remove this class which is inserted into the head of the page as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">#my_element_1 {border-radius: 12.5px;
...
}</style>
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the whole style block? Or that specific style?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

create a style tag:

```
var style = $("<style />", {
                id  : 'myStyleTag',
                type: 'text/css',
                html: "#my_element_"+MaxElements+" {"+ xCSSCode +"}"
}).appendTo("head");
```

to remove

```
style.remove();
// or
$('#myStyleTag').remove();
```

Comment: What about checking if more than 1 of that style is already in head, and the remove the previous one?

Comment: @SteveWorks - something like `if ($('style').length > 1) ... `

Answer (score 2):

I would store the elements in an object:

```
var styles = {};

...

styles[some_identifier] = $("<style>", {
    type: "text/css",
    html: "#my_element_"+MaxElements+" {"+ xCSSCode +"}"
}).appendTo("head");
```

You can remove the style tag easily:

```
styles[some_identifier].remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#my_element').removeClass('hidden');
 // also
 $('#my_element').addClass('hidden');
```